# Colour expressions for Chart type report on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

My Graph is populating this based on Table 2 results : At No 3 there is unique colour yellow there in table . how can I apply colour yellow bar at 3 , rest of them are one colour please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BackgroundColor` property of the row, it needs to be an expression that looks something like

```
=IIF(Fields!Person_Colour.value="01-Yellow", "Yellow", "White")
```

or some other logical test...

Each cell that you want to be yellow needs to have that expression as the "BackgroundColor"